# Issues with citing: wrong output in the text only for ONE author

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am writing my thesis using TeXstudio. I have a .tex file with my writings and a .bib file with my references, where I have so far copy pasted references from Google Scholar to the .bib file, and fed those into the .tex document (and of course those reference appear then at the end of the document). All my references have the format:

```
@article{keyword,
  title={Title},
  author={Surname, Name and Surname, Name},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={Number},
  number={Number},
  pages={Pages},
  year={Year},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

So far I haven't had any trouble when I use the command \cite or \citep in my .tex document, but with ONE particular author (and please let me know if this isn't appropiate to do):

```
@article{altmann2004b,
  title={Language-mediated eye movements in the absence of a visual world: The ‘blank screen paradigm’},
  author={Altmann, Gerry TM},
  journal={Cognition},
  volume={93},
  number={2},
  pages={B79--B87},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Whenever I use `\cite{altmann2004b}` or `\citep{altmann2004b}`, instead of the surname only, there is always `G. Altmann (2004)` in the text. I repeat, this only happens with THIS author (or surname).

What could it be? May it be related to the surname itself (that it may be in conflict with some command or function)? May it be some sort of bug?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I was trying to narrow down the problem. My document starts with something like this:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize =12pt, pagesize=pdftex, parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, english]{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\cite{altmann2004b}


\bibliography{references.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\end{document}
```

Now I realized that when I run this single reference, everything is fine. However, as soon as I cite another reference (as the one below) and add another line with `\citep{ altmann1999b}` from the same author, the problem begins:

```
@article{altmann1999b,
    title={Incremental interpretation at verbs: Restricting the domain of subsequent reference},
    author={Altmann, Gerry TM and Kamide, Yuki},
    journal={Cognition},
    volume={73},
    number={3},
    pages={247--264},
    year={1999b},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a Minimal Working Example? This questions shows us nothing about biliography packages you are using. Thus, it is hard to help you without simply guessing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us the complete code, from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`, after removing unrelated stuff. From the information that you provided so far I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question above. Feel free to remove whatever is unnecessary and please let me know if I am still missing something.

Comment: Better to use `setspace` than setting `\baselinestretch` like that. See KOMA's documentation. You don't need `\setcounter{page}{0}`.

Comment: Do you have any warnings or errors. At the moment your reported behaviour can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of the initial is to ensure that each author list is unique i.e. that `Author 1 and Author 2` is not confused or conflated with `Author 1`. This is the intended behaviour and not a problem to be solved.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Apparently, I mistakenly had one reference without the compound name (Gerry instead of Gerry TM) so yes, it took it as two authors instead of one. Now it works. Sorry for the inconvenience!! :S